# How to regex match a string from text?

Tags: php, regex

I try to learn regex by match this string from a text in regexr.com and want to echo the output. Currently I'm only able to match the protocol `http` or `https`. This the string i want to match:

> https://s04.solidfilesusercontent.com/NGU0MGIwZTg1MDU0MjI5YzE3YzM3NDQ4ZWJhNjVhN2Y3ZGVmN2EwNDoxYkFmRkY6ODZvb29qRG8tdFluMXl2TU1hR1dBN19ockt3/v8grz2RpkMkWd/As_The_Gods_Will_%282014%29-1.mp4

And this's the text

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7136426241719979"
     data-ad-slot="9347712042"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</center>
        </div>
            <div id="report">
                <ol class="list-group" id="link">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="btn" onclick=" $(this).closest(\'li\').remove();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a><a target='blank' href='https://s04.solidfilesusercontent.com/NGU0MGIwZTg1MDU0MjI5YzE3YzM3NDQ4ZWJhNjVhN2Y3ZGVmN2EwNDoxYkFmRkY6ODZvb29qRG8tdFluMXl2TU1hR1dBN19ockt3/v8grz2RpkMkWd/As_The_Gods_Will_%282014%29-1.mp4'>https://s04.solidfilesusercontent.com/NGU0MGIwZTg1MDU0MjI5YzE3YzM3NDQ4ZWJhNjVhN2Y3ZGVmN2EwNDoxYkFmRkY6ODZvb29qRG8tdFluMXl2TU1hR1dBN19ockt3/v8grz2RpkMkWd/As_The_Gods_Will_%282014%29-1.mp4</a></li>

                </ol>       
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
<!-- Histats.com  START  (standard)-->
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=%27http://s10.histats.com/js15.js%27 type=%27text/javascript%27%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>
```

My regex so far and I'm still stuck

```
/^(http|https):\\/\\/[a-z0-9]/
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [**regex info tag**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and provide your desired programming language. In your expression, you have not specified any quantifier (`*`, `+`, `*?` or `+?`) right after your character class, additionally which part of the string shall be extracted/matched?

Comment: @Jan i test regex in php

Comment: @Jan now, i can match the string. but it return boolean 1 when echo the result preg_match. what's wrong?

Comment: @jan this;s my regex i generate from regexr.com `/.*?(mp4)/`

Comment: Again, **what** do you need from the string? The filename? Do you want to make sure, that the string **ends** with `.mp4` ? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Jan i want to match the whole string.

Comment: @davidmarc – If you change the s04 to s05 in the host name, do you still want a match?  What if you change the NGU0 to MGU0 in the path?  I'm under the impression you want to store the whole URL but you only want to match the file name ("As_The_Gods_Will_%282014%29-1.mp4").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of that you want to match.  If you want an exact match:

```
/^https:\/\/s04\.solidfilesusercontent\.com\/NGU0MGIwZTg1MDU0MjI5YzE3YzM3NDQ4ZWJhNjVhN2Y3ZGVmN2EwNDoxYkFmRkY6ODZvb29qRG8tdFluMXl2TU1hR1dBN19ockt3\/v8grz2RpkMkWd\/As_The_Gods_Will_%282014%29-1\.mp4$/
```

If you want just the host:

```
/^https:\/\/s04\.solidfilesusercontent\.com\//i
```

(Though I can't recall if PHP's methods require a full match.  If that's true, end that with `.*$`)

If you want a pattern based on that host:

```
/^https?:\/\/s[0-9]{2}\.solidfilesusercontent\.com\//i
```

This will match hosts named `s01` through `s99`.

If you wanted to match some of the path, say to find the MP4 files:

```
/\.mp4%/i
```

Matching more of the path:

```
/[\w\/+=]{32}\/\S{1,256}\.mp4$/i
```

(This looks for 32 characters of base64 encoding, then a slash and a file name ending in `.mp4`)

Try these at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gB4bB8/1) to tailor them to your needs.

Comment: the static url is only protocol ( https ) and the domain ( solidfilesusercontent ) and other always change.

Comment: So then you want to match _only_ the protocol and domain?  You can do that with the following regex: `/^https:\/\/(?:[\w-]+\.)*solidfilesusercontent\.com\//i`  If that works for you, I'll add it (with an explanation and regex101 link) to my answer.

Comment: No, i want to match the whole url. but there's some part url that will always change.ex. sub-domain ( s04 ) and the path file. but only protocl and domain  that not change. i already update my question.